# how to do php 4 dimension array sorting

Tags: php

Cassandra Json format looks like this

```
    "recommendResult":[{
       "mediaId":"",
       "mediaEntry":[{
           "user1":{
               "name":"sooin",
               "rating":"3",
               "views":"2",
               "like":"ture",
               "comment":"good"
           },
           "user2":{
               "name":"sara",
               "rating":"1",
               "views":"4",
               "like":"ture",
               "comment":"good!"
           }
       }],
       "view":"4",
       "rating":"4",
       "like":"10",
       "smallUrl":"/photo/smallUrl",
       "largeUrl":"/photo/largeUrl",      
       "title":"aaaa"                  
    }]
```

Here is my php code

```
$rows=$column_family->get_range();
$count=0;

    foreach($rows as $key => $columns) {

     $returnkey[$count]=array('mediaId'=>$key,   
              'columns'=>$columns,'user'=>array_slice($columns,1,2));
     $count++;
}
natcasesort($returnArray['key']['comment']['photoInfo']['view']);
print_r($returnArray['key']['comment']['photoInfo']['view']);
```

I am trying to sort based on views.
i try to use natcasesort but it does not work.
Any thought for that.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't have a built-in sorting algorithm that will sort multidimensional arrays based on a certain key/value pair.  You should write your own sorting algorithm to handle this data.

Here's somewhere to get started (all of these can easily be modified to work with your particular array):

[Comparison of sorting algorithms](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/computersciencetheory/sortcomp.html)